# MSChart - Working with X axis of Time type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, mschart

I am trying to show some measured data on mschart.
Measures start at different time of day, but file always has data from 24h (measure every 1s => 86400 measures). I load this file into object with two properties of type DateTime and double (time of measure and it's value).

And now first problem

## 1.

I want chart to start at 6 AM and end at 6 AM, but it always show from midnight to midnight.

Connected problem. When i want to show night measures (10PM - 6AM) i have chart from 0 to 0(24) with data from 0-6 and 22-24 with line from 24 to 0 connecting them (point #2). So i want it to simply start at 10PM and end at 6AM.

## 2.

As i said measures can start at any time. Lets say from 2011-06-14 10:00:00 till 2011-06-15 09:59:59. When I am showing data from midnight to midnight (point #1) there is line from right to left (from data point at 23:59:59 to DP at 00:00:00). Is there a way to remove it ?

## 3.

I have found that there is ChartArea.AxisX.Minimum/Maximum. In property editor it is visible as datetime, but changing it's value calls error with message, that this value is not a correct double value. When at runtime I check this value i get System.Double type and value of NaN. So how can I set it ?? Probably changing this value correctly can solve issue #1.

Comment: ok, probably I've found the way to "solve" it by using indexed value. But if there is any more civilized way - I am still waiting ^_^